# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'rindex'

Tags: python, scrapy

**Setup**

I'm using Scrapy 0.24.4 and [Scrapy-ElasticSearch 0.5](https://github.com/knockrentals/scrapy-elasticsearch) to scrape a website and store the results in an elasticsearch instance I have running.

I've used [this blog post](http://blog.florian-hopf.de/2014/07/scrapy-and-elasticsearch.html) to set it all up, with the minor modification that I documented [here](http://blog.florian-hopf.de/2014/07/scrapy-and-elasticsearch.html?showComment=1413801748670#c1092074214387731109).

*settings.py*

```
BOT_NAME = 'blah'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['blah.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'blah.spiders'

ITEM_PIPELINES = [
  'scrapyelasticsearch.scrapyelasticsearch.ElasticSearchPipeline', 100
]

ELASTICSEARCH_SERVER = 'localhost' 
ELASTICSEARCH_PORT = 9200 
ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX = 'scrapy'
ELASTICSEARCH_TYPE = 'items'
```

**Problem**

If I run the following command to scrape a website:

```
scrapy crawl wiki -o wiki.json
```

With ITEM_PIPELINES commented out - then it works correctly and exports all results to a wiki.json file.

With ITEM_PIPELINES uncommented (e.g. set to enable piping results to elasticsearch) - I get the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 34, in load_object
   dot = path.rindex('.')
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'rindex'
```

**Notes**

- May or may not be relevant. I actually had to change my local copy of ElasticSearchPipeline python file to comment out [this block](https://github.com/knockrentals/scrapy-elasticsearch/blob/master/scrapyelasticsearch/scrapyelasticsearch.py#L39) which was causing syntax errors at the point at which it was indexing using uniq_id.

Any help hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid, stupid stupid. It was a syntax error!

Having an ITEM_PIPELINES list is deprecated, so it needs to be a dictionary, but my attempt at converting to a dictionary was terribly mangled:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = [
  'scrapyelasticsearch.scrapyelasticsearch.ElasticSearchPipeline', 100
]
```

That's not valid syntax. It should have been:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
  'scrapyelasticsearch.scrapyelasticsearch.ElasticSearchPipeline': 100
}
```